# Application configured incorrectly error C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, native

I'm new to c++. I made a c++ program using VS 2008 Professional. I started with the Win32 template that created a window for me. I compiled it on Vista 32. I brought the compiled exe to my old XP sp2 computer, and it tells me the application configuration is incorrect. Is there something im doing wrong? How do I make it platform independent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en) and make sure you use the release build of your application.

Comment: Then how could I make an application with no dependencies, this is a bit dissapointing because I transitioned from .Net with hopes of not having to worry about this stuff; can I just use VC 6 or something?

Comment: You can avoid the dependency by statically linking to the runtime support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that WINVER is set to a version that includes WinXP - it looks like the default target version of Windows for VS 2008 is Vista (0x0600).

Set the following preprocessor define:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
```

preferably using the Project Properties "C/C++/Preprocessor/Preprocessor Definitions" or the -D option on the cl.exe command line.  It's also possible that there's a targetver.h file that has this setting (depending on how your project got created initially).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(VS.85).aspx for more details.

Comment: That is a good idea to do, but probably not the problem based on the error that is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Your target system is missing the needed runtime files for that executable.

You can find it at: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en) or [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find which components lacks on target WinXP system. Then you should install appropriate redistributables.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties, set `"C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library"` to `"Multi-threaded (Debug)"`. After you rebuild, the application will no longer depend on `msvcr90.dll`. The application binary will, however, be somewhat larger.

Comment: Of course, for release builds you should use "Multi-Threaded" (not debug). Also this is a bad idea if your app itself consists of multiple DLLs.